# how to apply inner css in codeigniter controller single statement

Tags: php, codeigniter, jquery

Hello Friends I know we can apply css on view side but in certain condition i have to show a company availability or not using ajax which show status directly from controller & right now i want to apply css on that my code is same as above and here 'companyname' is my id and name of html input tag.

```
controller :
function get_companyname() {

        if (strlen($_POST['companyname']) >= 5) {

            $query = $this->company_model->verify_companyname($_POST['companyname']);
            if ($query > 0) {
                echo " Not Available";// i want to apply css here 

            } else {
                echo "Available"; // i want to apply css here

            }
        }
    } 


ajax code:

$('#companyname').keyup(function(){
    var companyname= $(this).val();
    if(companyname.length>=5){
         $('#companyname_status').text('searching....');
         if(companyname != ''){
             $.post('test',{ companyname:companyname},function(data){ //test redirects to controller function
                  $('#companyname_status').text(data);
             });
         }
         else{
             $('#companyname_status').text('');
         }
     }
 });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change you condition like this

```
if (strlen($_POST['companyname']) >= 5) {
    $query = $this->company_model->verify_companyname($_POST['companyname']);
    if ($query > 0) {
        echo 1;
    } else {
        echo 0;
    }
}
```

Post Request

```
$.post('test',{ companyname:companyname ,function(data){
    if(data == 1){
        $('#companyname_status').addClass('newclass');  
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks For Reply but how can i apply css on newclass

Comment: you can create css like this in view or your stylesheet .newclass{ color : red}

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the text inside  or  tag with some class. Define the class in CSS .
Else you can use the inline styles in span tag itself.
Example:

```
 echo "<span class=test>Available</span>";
```

In your CSS:

```
 .test {
   color: red;
  }
```

Another Way:

```
  echo "<span style=\"color:red;\">Available</span>";
```